# body-parser is decrypted, How can I solve this

Tags: body-parser

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: true }));
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

const Razorpay=require('razorpay')
var instance = new Razorpay({
    key_id: 'hgdfhbhdfbdh',
    key_secret: 'hdfhbvkjdhgsdk',
});
```

error

Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: Error: please examine your function logs to see the error cause: https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/logging#viewing_logs. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging. Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

Answer (score 0):

zaiger
I'm a novice. I started learning JS and React 2 weeks ago and I faced this issue.
Please try:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
app.use(express.json()) // for parsing application/json
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })) // for parsing application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```